# HTTP ERROR 500 when installing magento

Tags: php, magento, magento2

"The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

This is the error message my browser displayed.
I don't know why, I installed Magento on Windows and there was no problem, but when I install it on my Ubuntu, my browser say that, please help me and thank you for the help.

Comment: check the file permission for tmp , cache folders

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just increase /setup in behind
I look for another tutorial and i found this.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105821/magento-2-not-working-on-apache2-php7-and-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [error 500](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1) is an error on the server side.
Maybe you have a typo in your code which makes it break.

As you tried it on Windows, it could come from this as well, as Windows is not case sensitive with files, and ubuntu is.

You should try looking at the server logs to have more information.

Or else put those lines in your index.php, it should show you the errors and help you debugging it (there is a developper mode you can enable in Magento but I prefere adding all those lines to get more informations) :

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just increase /setup in behind
I look for another tutorial and i found this.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105821/magento-2-not-working-on-apache2-php7-and-ubuntu